# String Word Wrap in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to wrap my recipient email in my string assignment that has a very long list.

**Example:**

```
Dim MailList As String

MailList = _
"Email Address 1,"
"Email Address 2,"
"Email Address 3,"
'Go on until several lines
```

What command should i put in between each of the emails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` to concatenate the strings, and since you are breaking it into multiple lines, use an underscore after the ampersand.

Comment: Thanks dude it works. But u forgot to mention adding a space character between double quotes, ampersand and underscore.